# Java HTTPComponents SOAP request, SSLHandshake exception (PKIX path building failed)

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

I'm trying to sent a custom SOAP message to a specific webservice using HTTPComponents. We use a certificate for communication and the webservice endpoint is uses a certificate for the https encryption.

Via a custom Java action I'm trying to sent the SOAP message but at the point where I execute the httppost an error is thrown:

```
Executing request POST https://webserviceurl/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Exception While Connecting sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested     target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:      sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

I did some research on this issue and apparently Java needs the certificate which is used for the webservice URL in its cacerts. Using a Java tool called InstallCert I tried to add the certificate(s) to cacerts, but I still get this error.

PS: I also tried adding the certificate to cacerts using keytool, but no luck either.

So why is the connection failing. Is it correct that I need to add the endpoint certificate to the cacerts file? Any ideas on how to fix this issue / how to succesfully add the certificate to trusted certificates?

Here's my full java code which does the request:

```
 // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new File("C:/ourcert.p12"), "MyPass".toCharArray(),
                    new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();        

    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();


    Byte[] result = null;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    int timeoutConnection = 15000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
    int timeoutSocket = 35000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);         

    byte[] result1 = null; 


        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webserviceUrl);
        httppost.setHeader("soapaction", "aanleveren");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");


        System.out.println("Executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());

        try {
             HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(soapBericht,HTTP.UTF_8);
             httppost.setEntity(entity); 
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);// calling server
             HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();  //get response
             if (r_entity != null) {       
                 result1 = new byte[(int) r_entity.getContentLength()];  
                 if (r_entity.isStreaming()) {
                     DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
                             r_entity.getContent());
                     is.readFully(result1);
                 }
             }

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            Core.getLogger("SBR").log(LogLevel.WARNING,"ERROR " + E.getMessage() + E.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println("Exception While Connecting " +E.getMessage());
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpclient.close(); //shut down the connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it to the system root cert, try adding it your application trust.

```
keytool -import -alias <ALIAS_NAME> -keystore <your_app_trust>.jks -trustcacerts -file <CERTIFICATE_TO_ADD.der> -v
```

I had the same problem and it fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

A very usual case when you are using self signed certificates..
Try this:

```
                SSLContext sslContext = null;
                try
                {
                    sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException
                        {
                            return true;
                        }

                    }).build();
                }
                catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e)
                {
                    //Show some Msg
                }
                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                                            .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
                                                            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                                                            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                                                            .build();
```